# Undefined name '_change' when I tried to call it inside a method | flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I declared a counter as int and call it in a method, but i got an error of undefined counter name inside a method. //_flutter

Code:

```
//...proceed from statefulWidget

int _change = 0;
List view = [ ("jS), ("reactN") ];


//Method

void _myList () {
    
   setState(() {
  _change += 1;

});

}// End statefulWidget
```

I was wondering if there is any way I can get help to solve this little bug!

Comment: Hello, can you share your full code for it? And maybe try change your `_change` to `change`

Answer (score 0):

```
int change = 0;
List<String> view = ["jS", "reactN"];

// Your Method

void _myList () {
    setState(() { 
        change = change + 1;
    });
}

/// call your method like 
onTap: () {
    _myList();
}
```

Comment: Add more description to your question and what is the output of your code